# CPU and Memory consumtion ASP.NET Core WebAPI: Azure Webapp S2

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

The API isnt public yet and are idle with the following digits:

CPU: Around 5%
Memory: Around 33%

In your experience is this normal or too high? I'm wondering if I need to go up to an S3 before production. I will in the beginning maybe have around 50 users at the same time actively using the app with constant calls to the API. It's a dating-app.

Any input is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Lol, sorry I have no clue on what that api is doing, and the load it has to deal with so nobody will be able to give you an answer on this.

Comment: @Peter Bons Maybe my question was off. I don't know. Maybe I should create a scaffolded ASP.NET Core WebAPI and se how much it consumes at that point. Without having added anything

Comment: But that won't tell you anything meaningful. I would say give it a go and watch the metrics. If the cpu is > 80% and mem utilitization is > 80% for a long period of time then you can always scale up or out.  ( do note, I just used a random threshold value)

Comment: What I actually was trying to get at is what an API should consume in idle mode under normal circumstances. But I understand now that my question was bad because what is "normal"? I think that a scaffolded project would at least tell me what it at a bare minimum should consume, without having added anything. From there I can draw a conclusion regarding the numbers for my own API - if they in comparison are okey or not considering everything extra which is added.

Comment: Still, I don't think you should worry about idle consumption. Like I said, it does not tell much. If the idle consuption is 35% and with 1000 users it is 50% you're still safe.

Comment: Thanx Peter for your advice. I will give it a go in production with the S2 and scale up as soon as I reach dangerous levels.

Comment: Why you don't try some load testing tools to call your API. For example, you can make a scenario where you have 50 users calling the API at the same time. Then you can see how it behave.

Comment: Can you look into auto scale options for the web app ? Documentation link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling